# My website is not showing the lock (SSl Certificate)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

i am using wordpress, i have changed all website urls and images to https but the lock screen is not showing. I am using comodo ssl. Also i use a https redirect plugin. Any ideas? My website is www.tsigaradiko.com. Seems i have mixed http with https content but if you open all the images all direct to an https address

Answer (score 3):

it seems like you are using there "http://" assets. take a look in the developer's console and you'll see few errors like this one:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.tsigaradiko.com/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://www.tsigaradiko.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/to-tsigaradiko-email.jpg'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

When it will be switched, everything will be ok and the green lock sign will appear.

To open the console, click Ctrl + Shift + J or  Cmd + Opt + J, depends on your OS.

If you have a lot of pages, i recommend using [This tool](https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/) for fast crawling of your website.

Good luck!

Comment: You need to look at the developer console. Google `developer console <your preferred browser>` to find out how to get to this.